# Project GPM data does not exist. Creating new object. (Unity 3d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

Using Google Play Services v 0.9.37 Unity 5.5 I already tried to google it but didn't get any anything related to it. Problem is Google play services plugin not working properly even not showing any error except this in console:

"Project GPM data does not exist. Creating new object. UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) Google.PackageManager.LoggingController:Log(String) Google.PackageManager.ProjectManagerController:InflateProjectRecord(String) Google.PackageManager.ProjectManagerController:.cctor() UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes()"

any solution ?

Comment: Try to check this [github](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/376) and Google group [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/LVASxE9mmqY) if it can help you. The one who post this issue also encountered the same error that you are receiving "Project GPM data does not exist. Creating new object." So just try to check the post if you can get any information on how to solve this kind of issue.

Comment: Hi, @KENdi I already checked that post but his problem was with 3rd party Mediation. I tried to re-import google play sdk , tried in a different project and in sample apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 
Unity not support network connection show this shows this warning and don't forget to add testers in developer console.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error today after updating GPS. Which version of Google play services do you use ? Because, with the previous version, I didn't have this issue.

Comment: Hi I am using GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.37. Still looking for solution. Please let me know if you solved it @teddy kossoko